# Help avoiding damage to perforation wheels

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have an application in which I need to adjust the position of 2 perforation wheels along the y axis to regulate their distance from a film web edge.  Though the speed of this positioning will be quite slow (low FT), I am concerned about damaging the perforation wheels as they are pressed against a steel roller with significant force to ensure cutting.

I figure there a couple ways to prevent damage:

1) Reduce force (Fp) on perforation wheel during movement.
-Interrupts continuous operation of the machine

2) Spin the perforation wheel about the z axis proportionally to the speed of movement along the y axis, sort of like steering.  I would need to sync the two wheels together.

3) Do nothing: The wheel self corrects by deflecting in the y direction by some small angle

Context: The total travel of the perf wheels is unlikely to exceed an inch in total.  I do not currently know the pressure on the wheels, I don't know of an easy way to measure it either.

As the machine in its current form is in continuous use at the moment I cannot really trial many things for real.  Thanks for the advice.

[image]

Comment: Hard to say with more info. Are the perforation wheels expensive to replace? Are they supported by bearings? What kind?  Can they be altered? I'd suggest to keep it simple... over engineering brings its own problems. Make small changes and assess the result